# tagging serverless log group for a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, aws-serverless

I am creating a lambda function by referring the ink https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

The lambda gets created and in the stack I don't see any log group. If I invoke the lambda a log group automatically gets created and logs get written to the streams inside the log group.

I have 2 issues.

1. How to ensure that if ever the stack is deleted, the log group do not get deleted. I would want to keep the log group with the streams even if the stack is deleted.
2. How to tag the log group? I have used stack tags, and tags inside deploymentBucket, and in provider as well. However, the log group does not get tagged.

Answer (score 1):

> How to ensure that if ever the stack is deleted, the log group do not get deleted. I would want to keep the log group with the streams even if the stack is deleted.

Log group won't be deleted as you have not explicitly defined that in your template.

Because it might be using  this canned policy in the `Lambda Execution Role`.

> arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

> How to tag the log group? I have used stack tags, and tags inside deploymentBucket, and in provider as well. However, the log group does not get tagged.

If you want to tag the resources, then you have to define the log group inside the template and then reference the same. But unofortuantely tagging log groups is not supported yet

[AWS::Logs::LogGroup tag support #77](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/77) in Cloudformation. You can achieve this by [Cloudformation Custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)

I included an example custom resource for tagging the log group

[DeletionPolicy attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) as you are now including the log group creation inside the template.

```yaml
Description: "tag log groups"
Parameters:
  LogGroupName:
    Type: "String"
    Description: "Log Groups Name"
    Default: "myloggroup"
Resources:
  myLogGroup: 
  Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupName 
    RetentionInDays: 7
  LogGroupTaggingFunctionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: TagLogGroupPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:TagLogGroup
                Resource: "*"

  TagLogGroupFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'tag log groups'
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 60
      Role: !GetAtt LogGroupTaggingFunctionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import json
          import os
          import cfnresponse
          sts = boto3.client('logs')
          log_group_name = os.environ['LOG_GROUP_NAME']
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            print('Event:', json.dumps(event))
            request_type = event.get('RequestType', 'Update').upper()
            if request_type == 'CREATE':
              response = client.tag_log_group(
                logGroupName=log_group_name,
                tags={
                'Name': 'MyLogGroup'
                }
              )
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {})
              print(json.dumps(response))
            else:
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {})
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_GROUP_NAME:
            Ref: LogGroupName

  InvokeLogGroupTaggingLambda:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt TagLogGroupFunction.Arn
```